# Pandas: grouping and aggregation with multiple functions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, aggregate

## Situation

I have a pandas dataframe defined as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

headers = ['Group', 'Element', 'Case', 'Score', 'Evaluation']
data = [
    ['A', 1, 'x', 1.40, 0.59],
    ['A', 1, 'y', 9.19, 0.52],
    ['A', 2, 'x', 8.82, 0.80],
    ['A', 2, 'y', 7.18, 0.41],
    ['B', 1, 'x', 1.38, 0.22],
    ['B', 1, 'y', 7.14, 0.10],
    ['B', 2, 'x', 9.12, 0.28],
    ['B', 2, 'y', 4.11, 0.97],
]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=headers)
```

which looks like this in console output:

```
  Group  Element Case  Score  Evaluation
0     A        1    x   1.40        0.59
1     A        1    y   9.19        0.52
2     A        2    x   8.82        0.80
3     A        2    y   7.18        0.41
4     B        1    x   1.38        0.22
5     B        1    y   7.14        0.10
6     B        2    x   9.12        0.28
7     B        2    y   4.11        0.97
```

## Problem

I'd like to perform a grouping-and-aggregation operation on `df` that will give me the following result dataframe:

```
  Group  Max_score_value  Max_score_element  Max_score_case  Min_evaluation
0     A             9.19                  1               y            0.41 
1     B             9.12                  2               x            0.10
```

To clarify in more detail: I'd like to group by the `Group` column, and then apply aggregation to get the following result columns:

- `Max_score_value`: the group-maximum value from the `Score` column.
- `Max_score_element`: the value from the `Element` column that corresponds to the group-maximum `Score` value.
- `Max_score_case`: the value from the `Case` column that corresponds to the group-maximum `Score` value.
- `Min_evaluation`: the group-minimum value from the `Evaluation` column.

## Tried thus far

I've come up with the following code for the grouping-and-aggregation:

```
result = (
    df.set_index(['Element', 'Case'])
    .groupby('Group')
    .agg({'Score': ['max', 'idxmax'], 'Evaluation': 'min'})
    .reset_index()
)
print(result)
```

which gives as output:

```
  Group Score         Evaluation
          max  idxmax        min
0     A  9.19  (1, y)       0.41
1     B  9.12  (2, x)       0.10
```

As you can see the basic data is there, but it's not quite in the format yet that I need. It's this last step that I'm struggling with. Does anyone here have some good ideas for generating a result dataframe in the format that I'm looking for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting from the `result` data frame, you can transform in two steps as follows to the format you need:

```
# collapse multi index column to single level column
result.columns = [y + '_' + x if y != '' else x for x, y in result.columns]
​
# split the idxmax column into two columns
result = result.assign(
    max_score_element = result.idxmax_Score.str[0],
    max_score_case = result.idxmax_Score.str[1]
).drop('idxmax_Score', 1)

result

#Group  max_Score   min_Evaluation  max_score_case  max_score_element
#0   A       9.19             0.41               y                  1
#1   B       9.12             0.10               x                  2
```

---

An alternative starting from original `df` using `join`, which may not be as efficient but less verbose similar to @tarashypka's idea:

```
(df.groupby('Group')
   .agg({'Score': 'idxmax', 'Evaluation': 'min'})
   .set_index('Score')
   .join(df.drop('Evaluation',1))
   .reset_index(drop=True))

#Evaluation  Group  Element   Case  Score
#0     0.41      A        1      y   9.19
#1     0.10      B        2      x   9.12
```

---

Naive timing with the example data set:

```
%%timeit 
(df.groupby('Group')
 .agg({'Score': 'idxmax', 'Evaluation': 'min'})
 .set_index('Score')
 .join(df.drop('Evaluation',1))
 .reset_index(drop=True))
# 100 loops, best of 3: 3.47 ms per loop

%%timeit
result = (
    df.set_index(['Element', 'Case'])
    .groupby('Group')
    .agg({'Score': ['max', 'idxmax'], 'Evaluation': 'min'})
    .reset_index()
)
​
result.columns = [y + '_' + x if y != '' else x for x, y in result.columns]
​
result = result.assign(
    max_score_element = result.idxmax_Score.str[0],
    max_score_case = result.idxmax_Score.str[1]
).drop('idxmax_Score', 1)
# 100 loops, best of 3: 7.61 ms per loop
```

Comment: Oh, setting index explicitly and joining after that is a nice improvement.

Comment: I'm happy with the excellent answers from all the posters here. I think that for now I'll go with the solution with `join` from Psidom's answer here, because I like the low verbosity. It's ok that's it's a little bit slower, because the performance bottlenecks in my current program are elsewhere.

Answer (score 3):

You can use apply instead of agg to construct all the columns in one go.

```
result = (
    df.groupby('Group').apply(lambda x: [np.max(x.Score),
                              df.loc[x.Score.idxmax(),'Element'],
                              df.loc[x.Score.idxmax(),'Case'],
                              np.min(x.Evaluation)])
      .apply(pd.Series)
      .rename(columns={0:'Max_score_value',
                       1:'Max_score_element',
                       2:'Max_score_case',
                       3:'Min_evaluation'})
      .reset_index()
)



result
Out[9]: 
  Group  Max_score_value  Max_score_element Max_score_case  Min_evaluation
0     A             9.19                  1              y            0.41
1     B             9.12                  2              x            0.10
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is possible solution with `pd.merge`

```
>> r = df.groupby('Group') \
>>       .agg({'Score': 'idxmax', 'Evaluation': 'min'}) \
>>       .rename(columns={'Score': 'idx'})
>> for c in ['Score', 'Element', 'Case']:
>>   r = pd.merge(r, df[[c]], how='left', left_on='idx', right_index=True)
>> r.drop('Score_idx', axis=1).rename(columns={'Score': 'Max_score_value', 
>>                                             'Element': 'Max_score_element', 
>>                                             'Case': 'Max_score_case'})
       Evaluation  Max_score_value  Max_score_element Max_score_case
Group                                                               
A            0.41             9.19                  1              y
B            0.10             9.12                  2              x
```

Though it provides the desired output, I am not sure about if it's not less efficient than yours approach.

Answer (score 1):

My Take

```
g = df.set_index('Group').groupby(level='Group', group_keys=False)

result = g.apply(
    pd.DataFrame.nlargest, n=1, columns='Score'
)

def f(x):
    x = 'value' if x == 'Score' else x
    return 'Max_score_' + x.lower()

result.drop('Evaluation', 1).rename(columns=f).assign(
    Min_evaluation=g.Evaluation.min().values).reset_index()

  Group  Max_score_element Max_score_case  Max_score_value  Min_evaluation
0     A                  1              y             9.19            0.41
1     B                  2              x             9.12            0.10
```