# How to add Data to existing Pandas Dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So i am writing a program where i determine feature importance for about 55 features, and a few of them were categorical so i one-hot encoded them so my data analysis would make sense. I am now trying to consolidate the one-hot encoded features back into their original features so that i can get the total importance for each categorical feature.

here is my psuedo-code:

```
Importance = [.1,.2,.3,.4] 
Importance_labels = ['Sand_trap_10', 'Sand_trap_15', 'Sand_trap_20', 'Sand_trap_25']
Importances_df = pd.DataFrame({'Importance_labels':'Importance'})
```

and I want

```
Importance = [1]
Importance_ labels = ['Sand_trap']
Importance_df = pd.DataFrame({'Importance_labels':'Importance'})
```

It seems like this is a brute force way to solve this problem but i am having trouble loading the new lists from the loop and adding them to the dataframe of all the feature importance. This loop returns two lists, one populated with the new importance values, and one populated with the respective feature labels. Any ideas? also the sorting won't work.

Comment: Hi, please make your question [minimal, complete and verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thanks! Yeah this is my first time posting on stack.

Comment: I don't fully understand what want to accomplish. Do you want to sort the columns of your dataframe according to your importance vector?

Comment: My Goal is to replace the dummy features (i.e. the one-hot encoded ones) in my original Dataframe and their importances with the original feature and the summation of the importance of all of its dummy features.

Comment: I think your question is still difficult to understand. Could you add an example of an input dataframe (showing all data values) and the corresponding result dataframe that you're looking to obtain (like done in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45133853/pandas-grouping-and-aggregation-with-multiple-functions))? That may help.