# How to optmize while-loop on large dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, while-loop

I have a dataframe with 2345 lines. For each number of lines I need to randomly select lines and calculate the standard deviation of these selected lines 100 times.

The while-loop code I have created works when I run the code up to 500 lines. However, when I run for a 1000 or more the calculation is never completed - Python crashes before the calculations finish. Is there a way I can optimize this using other functions? allcmps is a DataFrame shaped (2345, 106).

```
lines = 2345
average = pd.Series()
z = 0
while (z <= lines):
    intermstdv = pd.Series()
    x = 0
    if z > lines-100:
        while (x <= lines - z):
            sample = allcmps.sample(z).mean().iloc[1:].std(ddof = 0)*mt.sqrt(12)
            intermstdv = intermstdv.append(pd.Series(sample), ignore_index = True)
            x = x + 1
    else:
        while (x <= 100):
            sample = allcmps.sample(z).mean().iloc[1:].std(ddof = 0)*mt.sqrt(12)
            intermstdv = intermstdv.append(pd.Series(sample), ignore_index = True)
            x = x + 1

    average = average.append(pd.Series(intermstdv.mean()),ignore_index = True)
    z = z + 1
```

I would expect to get a Series object with 2345 lines, each of the average figures I received on the while-loop. However, I don't get any results because JupyterLab crashes before calculations finish. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to SO, your question is not reproducible and the *allcmps* is unclear, please do take some time to read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)?

Comment: With dataframe problems it's always really helpful if you can add to your post a print-out of a small example input dataframe, as well as a print-out of your desired result dataframe ([this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45133853/7306999) shows an example).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I can't add the dataframe object because it's too large, but I have added some clarifications. Please let me know it it's still not clear. Thank you!

Comment: What happens if you run it in a script? does it finish and if not, what exception is raised?

Comment: You could try inserting calls to the garbage collector. You really produce a lot of temporary objects. Maybe you get into memory problems because the memory is not freed in time. Just wildly guessing, but it could be worth a try. Add `import gc` and in your loop `gc.collect()` this will slow down the execution, but maybe it runs then.