# I'm trying to speed up dictionary and dataframe code that takes too long

Tags: python, pandas, performance, dictionary

I have a dictionary. Every key is a client, and every value is that client's trading history, in pandas dataframe format, each row looks like:

```
bought 2pm yesterday     |      sold 5pm today    | 5 units  | 'Apple Stock'
bought 2:05 pm yesterday | sold 2:15 pm yesterday | 10 units | 'Samsung Stock'
```

I'm trying to compute exposure per client. This means I want a dataframe per client that looks like this:

```
Time | Apple | Samsung | Tesla | Netflix |
1:55 |   0   |    0    |   0   |    0    |
2:00 |   5   |    0    |   0   |    0    |
2:05 |   5   |    10   |   0   |    0    |
2:10 |   5   |    10   |   0   |    0    |
2:15 |   5   |    0    |   0   |    0    |
```

For now I have code that works, but the number of clients and number of rows per client is simply too big for my basic computations, and the code takes waaaaay to long.
I've worked on it for a day or two and cant seem to speed it up more

I'm copy pasting a sample of my code with some irrelevant stuff removed and privacy stuff changed.

```
nopdic = {}
#array is simply a list of 5 minute seperated times
arr = [str((datetime(2015, 1, 1, 0, 0)) + timedelta(minutes=5 * i))
   for i in range(int((datetime.today() - datetime(2016, 1, 1, 0, 0)).total_seconds() / 60.0 / 5))]
k=0
for i in iddic.keys():
    temp = iddic[i]
    temp['opening_time'] = pd.to_datetime(temp['opening_time'])
    temp['closing_time'] = pd.to_datetime(temp['closing_time'])
#first i round the times to fit in my 5 minute time series (so if you open at 2:01 counts as 2pm)

    temp['roundstart'] = temp['opening_time'].apply(lambda y: y -timedelta(minutes=y.minute) + timedelta(minutes=(y.minute) // 5 * 5) - timedelta(seconds=y.second))

    temp['roundend'] = iddic[i]['closing_time'].apply(lambda y: y - timedelta(minutes=y.minute) + timedelta(minutes=(y.minute) // 5 * 5) - timedelta(seconds=y.second))


#now comes the loop where i check every line of clients trading history
    nopdic[i] = pd.DataFrame(index=arr, data=0, columns=temp['symbol'].unique())
    for j in range(len(temp)):
        start = str(temp['roundstart'].iloc[j])
        end = str(temp['roundend'].iloc[j])
        units = temp['how_many_units']
        symbol = temp['symbol'].iloc[j]`

#this line is the most important, as it inputs the number of units into the rows between opening and closing time

        nopdic[i][symbol][start:end] += units
```

My attempt at a MRE:

```
arr = [str((datetime(2015, 1, 1, 0, 0)) + timedelta(minutes=5 * i)) for i in range(int((datetime.today() - datetime(2016, 1, 1, 0, 0)).total_seconds() / 60.0 / 5))]
dictionaryofexposure = {}

for i in dictionaryofclients.keys:

    tradingdata = dictionaryofclients[i]
    nopdic[i] = pd.DataFrame(index=arr, data=0, columns=temp['symbol'].unique())
    for j in range(len(tradingdata))
        start = tradingdata[i]['start_time'].iloc[j]
        end = tradingdata[i]['end_time'].iloc[j]
        symbol = tradingdata[i]['symbol'].iloc[j]
        units = tradingdata[i]['how_many_units']

        dictionaryofexposure[i]['symbol'][start:end] += units
```

I've tried stuff like taking computations in and out of the loop and deleting as many lines as possible - also dabbled in multithreading but not sure if its useful for this. The next thing I'm trying in converting stuff to arrays.

sample input and desired output code

```
inputstefan = pd.DataFrame(columns=['open_time','close_time','symbol','lots'], data =[['2023-07-31 23:07:00', '2023-07-31 23:18:00', 'NFLX', 10],['2023-07-31 23:14:00', '2023-07-31 23:21:00', 'NFLX', 15],['2023-07-31 23:12:00', '2023-07-31 23:17:00', 'TSLA', 5]])
inputchris = pd.DataFrame(columns=['open_time','close_time','symbol','lots'], data = [['2023-07-31 23:08:00', '2023-07-31 23:17:00', 'AAPL',5],['2023-07-31 23:16:00', '2023-07-31 23:22:00', 'NFLX', 10]])
iddic = {'stefan':inputstefan, 'chris':inputchris}

outputstefan = pd.DataFrame(columns= ['time','NFLX','TSLA'])
outputstefan['time'] = ['2023-07-31 23:05:00','2023-07-31 23:10:00','2023-07-31 23:15:00','2023-07-31 23:20:00']
outputstefan['NFLX'] = [10,25,15,0]
outputstefan['TSLA'] = [0,5,0,0]

outputchris = pd.DataFrame(columns= ['time','NFLX','AAPL'])
outputchris['time'] = ['2023-07-31 23:05:00','2023-07-31 23:10:00','2023-07-31 23:15:00','2023-07-31 23:20:00']
outputchris['NFLX'] = [0,0,5,0]
outputchris['AAPL'] = [5,5,0,0]

dictionaryofexposure = {'stefan':outputstefan,'chris':outputchris}
outputstefan
              time      NFLX  TSLA
0  2023-07-31 23:05:00    10     0
1  2023-07-31 23:10:00    25     5
2  2023-07-31 23:15:00    15     0
3  2023-07-31 23:20:00     0     0
```

Comment: the code required the necessary indentation.

Comment: there are undefined variables in the example code.
the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: ok i'll work on it - its my first post

Comment: understood, this guide might help on how to ask a good question:
[how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Pandas (and Numpy) are really optimized for vectorized operations. You can expect a significant speed-up if you can replace your apply-calls and loops with vectorized operations (example [here](https://www.exxactcorp.com/blog/Deep-Learning/how-to-speed-up-python-pandas-by-over-300x)).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. SO is for specific questions, but there's no explicit question here and the help you need isn't very specific. Check out [ask]. You should also make a [mre]; for specifics see [reproducible pandas examples](/q/20109391/4518341). That said, it looks like this answer will help you: [Don't iterate over rows in a DataFrame](/a/55557758/4518341)

Comment: as two of you have kind of suggested, i'd love to get vectorization to work but cant figure out how to use in this specific case
also let me know if my MRE isnt on point

Comment: should i create a mock dataframe so people can copy paste it?

Comment: Adding some code lines that when executed generate the mock input dataframe (or dictionary?) would be most appreciated (see example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45133853/pandas-grouping-and-aggregation-with-multiple-functions)).

Comment: `start = tradingdata[i]['start_time'].iloc[j]; end = tradingdata[i]['start_time'].iloc[j]` Won't start and end have exactly the same value?

Comment: Nick you're right - i didnt code that part of the MRE well - i edited it

Comment: i also added sample input and output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given:

```
inputstefan = pd.DataFrame(columns=['open_time','close_time','symbol','lots'], data =[['2023-07-31 23:07:00', '2023-07-31 23:18:00', 'NFLX', 10],['2023-07-31 23:14:00', '2023-07-31 23:21:00', 'NFLX', 15],['2023-07-31 23:12:00', '2023-07-31 23:17:00', 'TSLA', 5]])
inputchris = pd.DataFrame(columns=['open_time','close_time','symbol','lots'], data = [['2023-07-31 23:08:00', '2023-07-31 23:17:00', 'AAPL',5],['2023-07-31 23:16:00', '2023-07-31 23:22:00', 'NFLX', 10]])
```

Doing:

```
# I assume there's a better way to define who it came from but...
inputstefan["name"] = "stefan"
inputchris["name"] = "chris"
df = pd.concat([inputstefan, inputchris])
for col in ("open_time", "close_time"):
    # Convert to datetime
    df[col] = pd.to_datetime(df[col])
    # Floor to Nearest 5min
    df[col] = df[col].dt.floor("5T")

# This will likely be the slowest step, as it's just a for loop.
df['time'] = df.apply(
    lambda x: pd.date_range(x.open_time, x.close_time, freq="5T", closed='left'),
    axis=1,
)

# Now we can just explode, pivot, and sum
output = (
    df.explode("time")
      .pivot_table(
          index=["name", "time"],
          columns="symbol", 
          values="lots",
          aggfunc="sum",
          fill_value=0,
          )
)

# Inspect the cross section "stefan"
print(output.xs("stefan"))
```

Output:

```
symbol               AAPL  NFLX  TSLA
time                                 
2023-07-31 23:05:00     0    10     0
2023-07-31 23:10:00     0    25     5
2023-07-31 23:15:00     0    15     0
```

Comment: Wow. Thanks. Pivot tables look really powerful. I'll try to read up on them.

Comment: also your way of flooring is much better than mine

Comment: Note: in pandas [version 2.0.0](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v2.0.0.html#removal-of-prior-version-deprecations-changes) the `closed` argument for `date_range()` was removed in favor of the `inclusive` argument.

Comment: @user22191883 If this answer solved your question, then please mark it as the accepted answer.